# Publicación de mi proyecto Angular con diferentes rutas de servidores

Tags: angular

Quisiera saber si en angular al momento de publicar mi proyecto, existe alguna forma de dejar la url del servidor a donde me voy a pegar para extraer los datos visible y poder cambiarla , como se hace en una publicación de un proyecto en `C# .Net` en el cual se realiza la publicación y se puede modificar el `web.config`.

Estoy publicando mi proyecto con el comando `ng build --prod` el cual me genera una estructura de archivos y carpetas las cuales copio en el servidor donde voy a publicar, al momento de realizar la publicación debo cambiar esta variable a true para que tome la url de producción y no la de desarrollo.

[image: Servicio que provee la url a los servicios]

El problema es que al momento de publicar se puede hacer en tres o cuatro ambientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes crear varios archivos con la configuracion
del ambiente que tu quieras con la actualizacion de la url servicio

ejemplo:

crea tres archivos con los nombres(puedes crear los ambientes que tu necesites qa1, staging, ..etc):

environment.ts
  environment.qa.ts 
  environment.prod.ts

para cada archivo agrega la clase con las propiedades correspondientes para cada ambiente
ejemplo environment.ts  //environment dev

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  environmentName: 'Dev',
  apiUrl: 'localhost/miservicio/'
};
```

//en la clase componente donde requieras la url del servicio
//se agrega el import

```
import { environment } from 'src/environment';
```

y en el constructor se agrega la variable

constructor() {

```
this.urlServicio = environment.apiUrl;
```

}
}

en el archivo de configuracion se agregan la ruta de los archivos
para los correspondientes ambientes.

```
"build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
...
}
}
```

finalmente cuando generas el paquete de produccion

ng build --configuration prod

---

----------Ahora suponiendo que quieres cambiar la apiurl para un proyecto ya compilado es evidente que se necesita un archivo extra digamos

envConfiguracion.js

a este achivo agregas la declaracion de una variable global.

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};

  // API url
  window.__env.apiUrl = 'http://urlApi';//parametro externo.

}(this));
```

//en index se agrega la referencia

//en el archivo de configuracion de angular se agrega la direccion para que sea parte del paquete

```
  "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/envConfiguracion.js"
            ]
```

//ahora puedes reutilizar tu metodo  de obtencion de url GetUrlEnvironent

```
 const browserWindow = window || {};
  const browserWindowEnv = browserWindow['__env'] || {};
```

var parametroURL=  browserWindowEnv.apiUrl;

Comment: Pero necesito poder decir a cual servidor o a cual ambiente va a ir cuando ya se encuentre compilado el proyecto , supongamos que tengo un archivo config para angular el cual define a que ambiente va a ir cambiando la url o poniendo un true o false, hay forma de hacerlo ?

Comment: solo reutiliza tu metodo get api url  y como puedes ver agrega dos variables globales una dev y otra con prod dependiendo de donde quieras publicar. puede ser modificado el archivo envConfig js